# How to update LocationRequest in java Android app devolopment

Tags: java, android, location

The location dependency I am using is: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1`

```
locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, 1000 * DEFAULT_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)
                .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(1000 * MIN_UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(1000)
                .build();

        sw_gps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(sw_gps.isChecked()){
                    locationRequest.setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                }else {
                    locationRequest.setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                }
            }
        });
```

`setPriority()` is depreciated so how should I update the priority in the if else conditions?

```
@Deprecated
    @NonNull
    public LocationRequest setPriority(int priority) {
        zzae.zza(priority);
        this.zza = priority;
        return this;
    }
```

That's the depreciated function from the file `LocationRequest.class`

Answer (score 0):

To update the priority for the location request without using the deprecated setPriority() method, you can utilize the LocationRequest.Builder and its method setPriority() directly when the switch is toggled. Here's how you can achieve that:

```
sw_gps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(sw_gps.isChecked()){
        locationRequest = locationRequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .build();
    } else {
        locationRequest = locationRequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .build();
    }
}
});
```